# Stripe - recurring contrib not in Civi

Tags: stripe

We've set up Stripe as our payment processor.

Non-recurring/renewing memberships and contributions work fine and Civi is updated accordingly.

Everything seems correct when creating a new recurring contribution.  Record added to Civi, email sent, etc.

The recurring contributions occur as scheduled. Stripe shows successful events, credit cards are charged, and the webhooks show 100% success as well. The Stripe cleanup job runs hourly with no hiccups. However, there is no record in Civi for the additional contributions. Also, there is no record in the financial transaction table underneath.

What am I missing?  Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have webhook created for the site?

Comment: Yes, there is a webhook, it appears to be working, per the stripe webhook reports